# Fedora unable to detect USB or wireless networks?

Tags: usb, gnome3, wifi, devices, fedora

I installed Fedora(Gnome) 19 on a Dell Inspiron with Intel i3 processor, and a factory built-in Windows 7 home premium OS.
The installation process completed successfully. But now when I log into Fedora I don't have internet. There are no wireless networks available, although another laptop with Windows 8 detects about 10 wireless networks in range.

I tried plugging in an ethernet cable, but nothing would happen and still no internet connection, and Bluetooth too does not have any networks.
I Googled and found a suggestion of installing `bluez-hid2hci`, but since I don't have internet, I downloaded the packages on a USB from another computer and came to install them on the laptop.

**The Problem:**
Fedora couldn't detect USB devices.
I tried mounting the USB but couldn't find it anywhere. Not even in `/var/log/messages`.
I ran the command `tail -f /var/log/messages` to see life messages and I inserted and removed the USB but no changes.

Here's the output I get: [image: photo of the screen showing tail -f /var/log/messages output]

**My Question:**
Why Can't Fedora detect wireless networks and USB drivers?

Comment: please [edit] your question to add the output of the command `lspci` ans `lsusb` (you can copy paste text from terminal with `Ctrl + caps + c`).  Also please try to ask one question at a time next time .

Comment: Addition to above, paste the output of "cat /proc/partitions"

Comment: What happens if you plus in the ethernet cable and reboot? Maybe it might detect it during boot. Also, add the result of the commands Kiwy referred.

Comment: @Kiwy I can not copy the output of the command `lspci` and `lsusb` because now I am using a different laptop to ask this question,and the the other Laptop with Fedora does not have internet, so there is no way to transfer the data of the output to this site.Sorry about that, but I can take a picture of it.

Comment: @JMCF125 I tried plugging in the Ethernet cable and rebooting,but still nothing different and still no internet connection.

Comment: @SHW same problem as with getting the output for ^Kiwy

Comment: Please add the output that ppl have asked for 2 times now! We need more info, what you've provided isn't enough for us to assist!

Comment: @Andy There are other ways to transfer data between machines, maybe you can use these.

Comment: Take a picture as you did with `tail -f /var/log/messages`, or use a live CD to copy the info to a flash drive. It seems you're not very interested solving this problem.

Comment: @JMCF125 Fedora won't detect a live CD or DVD either.I am still interested in solving this problem.

Comment: I mean for you to **boot** from it. Only BIOS needs to detect it. BTW, why don't you take a picture as you did before?